# wp8-show default local image as source of image control while Absolute URL image is loading and displayed in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I am beginner in windows phone 8 development. Actually, I have created web service project which parses a xml document and displays image and text as list in listbox control. I successfully did that. The problem is when network strength is good my app will parse xml document and display image quickly without error., 
but, when my internet strength is slow, it will successfully parse service xml but it takes too much time to display images in list.

so what am trying to do is I want to show default local image on image control till it displays image from xml service.

I have searched a lot. but it won't help me.
Please some one give me solution for this

here is my code

Xaml code:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="listbox" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="White">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="moviesGrid" Tag="{Binding Title}" Tap="moviesGrid_OnTap" Background="#FF3D89D4" Margin="0,0,0,3" Width="480">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="subCatName" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,0,0,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontFamily="Times New Roman" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="28"/>
                        <Image x:Name="subCatImage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="90" Width="90" Margin="5,5,5,5" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and my CS code

```
    List<SingleRss> _singleRsses = new List<SingleRss>();

                   SingleRss _singleRss = new SingleRss
                    {
                        Title = _title,
                        ImageSource = _imageSource,

                    };
                    _singleRsses.Add(_singleRss);
                }
            }
            listbox.ItemsSource = _singleRsses;
```

Simply said : how to show default local image as source of image control till the Absolute URL image being displayed in windows phone 8 apps.,

thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, use both in ItemTemplate, local on bottom, remote on top. While the remote image is being loaded, nothing is rendered there and the local is visible. When the remote image is rendered, it covers the local image.

```
<Grid x:Name="moviesGrid" Tag="{Binding Title}" Tap="moviesGrid_OnTap" Background="#FF3D89D4" Margin="0,0,0,3" Width="480">
    <TextBlock x:Name="subCatName" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,0,0,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontFamily="Times New Roman" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="28"/>
    <Image x:Name="localImage" Source="/Assets/MyPlaceholderPicture.jpg" Height="90" Width="90" Margin="5,5,5,5" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Image x:Name="subCatImage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="90" Width="90" Margin="5,5,5,5" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks you igrali., i got result exactly what am looking for with your answer., thank you once again

Comment: @PunniyamMoorthi mark as answer if it helps so that it helps others, too.